# how to set the page size to a4 in windows form for pdf report generation using asp.net?

Tags: report, rdlc

I am working on a windows application wherein I am unable to set the page size to a4 sheet. While taking print or saving the report as pdf the content of the report is expanded to 2-3 pages.How to overcome this?

I do have tried using using these

iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
then also i am unable to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content of the report doesn't fit on a single page it will expand and of course need multiple pages. Unless you're completely certain that the data would fit a single page, there is no way of stopping this from happening.

But if you're completely positive that it would fit a single page, make sure that all the elements have the property `Keep contents together on a single page, if possible` *checked* and that both properties that add a page break are *unchecked* (`Add a page break before` and `Add a page break after`).

Below is an image as an example.

[image]

---

**Edit:** Including the `Page` properties of a regular A4 sized Report.

[image]

Comment: i do have done this but then also same problem I am facing

Comment: Read carefully what i wrote, it's impossible to limit the report to a single page if the content exceeds the `PageSize`. I'll edit my answer to include the sizes of an A4 page.

Comment: kindly go through the image and suggest me to proceed by either using table or custom design? Currently i have used custom design.

Comment: You'll have to add the image to your question. Perhaps include a screenshot of your Report Builder as well.

Comment: You could reduce the page `Margins` and set fixed widths to your Columns and TextBoxes so it doesn't grow beyond the page's maximum width.

Comment: i have completely reduced the margins

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the margin size as ( 0.1in, 0.1in, 0.1in, 0.1in )
and Page Size as ( 8.27in, 11.69in ) It may work